# Pass prop to styles for EmotionJS?

Tags: reactjs, emotion

How can I have a prop defined by state which I pass to my EmotionJS styles?

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  state = {
    menuOpen: true,
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <menu className={menuStyle} menuopen={this.state.menuOpen ? 'true' : undefined }>
    )
  }

const menuStyle = css`
  display: ${menuopen ? 'block' : 'none'};

`
```

I don't really understand this error message:

> Interpolating functions in css calls is deprecated and will be removed
>   in the next major version of Emotion. If you want to have a css call
>   based on props, create a function that returns a css call like this
>   let dynamicStyle = (props) => css`color: ${props.color}` It can be
>   called directly with props or interpolated in a styled call like this
>   let SomeComponent = styled('div')`${dynamicStyle}`

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using the cx function to combine classes:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  state = {
    menuOpen: true,
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <menu className={this.state.menuOpen ? menuStyle : cx(menuStyle, menuStyleClosed)}>
    )
  }

const menuStyleClosed = css`
  display: none;

`
```

Answer (score 0):

You also try using the `css` and `cx` named exports, and pass an object with keys as the name of the class name and values as the prop name like so:

```
import { css, cx } from 'emotion';

const menuStyleOpen = css
  display: 'block';
`;

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  state = {
    menuOpen: true,
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <menu
        className={cx({
          [menuStyleOpen]: menuOpen,
        })}
      />
    );
  }
}
```